# VB.NET User control Referencing Form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a form (frmwizard) which I am using to create a wizard like interface. The form contains a usercontrol and a button (for testing). There is also a function on the form called "NextPage"

The form loads a usercontrol (ucpage1) on load and the usercontrol has a button on it that when clicked attempts to call a function on the main form as per below:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    frmWizard.Nextpage(me.name)
End Sub
```

Within my function called "NextPage"  have the following for testing.

```
Public Sub NextPage(ByVal CurrentPage As String)
    MessageBox.Show(UserControl1.Controls.Count)
End Sub
```

When I call the function from the form itself (via the button) I get the result of 1, when i call the function via the User Control, I get the result as 0

I'm sure there is something simple I need to do, but i'm unsure what i've overlooked.

I am trying to make the button on the user-control Save the data within the control and then to browse to the next wizard page. Hopefully this is enough information

Comment: After rebuilding the project i think i have worked out why it doesn't let me navigate. If i setup the startup form as my Wizard form, it works fine, but if i startup to my main form then it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Codependance is a bad idea, as it locks the two types together for the future. If your user control really needs to invoke the form, you should instead have it raise an event and handle the event in your form.

```
Public Class MyUserControl
    Public Event OnNextPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Private Sub btnNextPage_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNextPage.Click
        RaiseEvent OnNextPage(Me, New EventArgs)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub MyUserControl_OnNextPage(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyUserControl1.OnNextPage ' , MyUserControl2.OnNextPage, etc...
        MessageBox.Show(DirectCast(sender, MyUserControl).Controls.Count)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for that. What is the best way to handle this? Happy to change this and learn. There will be about 5 wizard User Controls and a single form, am i better using a form/module for this?

Comment: Think about how a regular control like a button works. It raises events (Clicked, MouseDown, etc...) for the outside world so they can use them as they please. You just need to do the same, design your user controls so they are independant and raise the events you need to consume in your form. Then just handle the events in your form as needed.